# Spring Boot, no console logging is available if --spring.config.location is provided while starting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a simple web app based on Spring Boot, I want to externalize my configuration using --spring.config.location when I start the app, like this:

```
java -jar app.jar --spring.config.location=file://home/user/application-dev.properties
```

When I start the app without --spring.config.location it does print all the logs in console, otherwise there's no output.

There're no logging-related properties neither in 'main' application.properties nor in the external config I'm trying to use.

The same thing happens when I use SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION env variable instead of passing the argument.

Comment: Please make sure that application-dev.properties and your application.properties are the same

Comment: @ronhash I've just copy/pasted application.properties to application-dev.properties and got the same result

Comment: Another try - ensure that the path is correct -you have a double slash there - //home - try /home

Comment: @ronhash That worked, thank you. I made mistake - actually app wasn't working at all. Now I see the logs, though now I see it doesn't actually override original properties by the properties from the provided config ;C